# Can we include a checkbox inside a text area in html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, regex, checkbox

Can we get a checkbox inside a text area in the html??

I was trying to develop an User Interface, i will share the code

```
<textarea title="JSON Input" id="json_data"  ></textarea>
```

In this, I need to add a checkbox, so that how much lines of json I will give, that should come with respective check boxes in each lines.

Suppose in my text area, I am entering a json of 5 Lines, I should get these 5 lines in the text area followed check boxes at the end of the line.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked){myFunction()}">
```

I am using above script for getting checkbox, but I am not getting the required output.Can we use any regex for this??

[image]

Comment: Can you create a demo for that?

Comment: yeah , i will, pls be here

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible or pretty to put tags into the textbox. I don't know your suggestions, but I have created two examples in one snippet which could help you

```css
.request-input {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.request-input .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.request-input .form-group input {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

.request-input .form-group .field-name::before,
.request-input .form-group .field-value::before,
.request-input .form-group .field-name::after,
.request-input .form-group .field-value::after {
  content: "\"";
}
```

```html
<form class="request-input">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="brace">{</div>
  </div>
  <!-- here are two inputs for the names and values -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <span class="field-name">
        <input type="text" name="field-name[]" class="field-input" value="name" />
      </span>
      <span class="colon">:</span>
      <span class="field-value">
        <input type="text" name="field-value[]" class="field-input" value="Ashish" />
      </span>
      <span class="comma">,</span>
      <span class="field-active">
        <input type="checkbox" name="field-active[]" class="field-input" checked="checked" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <span class="field-name">
        <input type="text" name="field-name[]" class="field-input" value="id" />
      </span>
      <span class="colon">:</span>
      <span class="field-value">
        <input type="number" name="field-value[]" class="field-input" value="007" />
      </span>
      <span class="field-active">
        <input type="checkbox" name="field-active[]" class="field-input" checked="checked" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <!-- here is only one input for the names and values -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field[]" class="field-input" value="&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Ashash&quot;," />
      </span>
      <span class="field-active">
        <input type="checkbox" name="field-active[]" class="field-input" checked="checked" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field[]" class="field-input" value="&quot;id&quot;:&quot;007&quot;" />
      </span>
      <span class="field-active">
        <input type="checkbox" name="field-active[]" class="field-input" checked="checked" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="brace">}</div>
  </div>
</form>
```